# FileNotFoundException thrown when WinCE tries to find message text for another exception in .NET CF 2.0

Tags: c#, exception, compact-framework, .net-2.0, windows-ce

I have a stupid WinCE application where I'm just trying to force an exception and get the exception message to be retrieved from the System.SR.dll which gets deployed to the device.

The code that I have throwing an exception is the following:

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient("abcd", 1234);
```

But when the SocketException tries to resolve it's message, it throws a FileNotFoundException with the following tacktrace:

> at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalGetSatelliteAssembly()
>   at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetSatelliteAssembly()
>   at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet()
>   at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString()
>   at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString()
>   at System.SRSupport.HasString()
>   at System.SRSupport.HasString()
>   at System.SR.HasString()
>   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketException.makeMessage()
>   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketException..ctor()
>   at System.Net.Dns.ResolveInternal()
>   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry()
>   at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.Connect()
>   at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient..ctor()
>   at WinCeMessage.Com.SocketBlaster.Blast()
>   at WinCeMessage.Form1.button1_Click()
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick()
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick()
>   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WnProc()
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc()
>   at Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterMainLoop()
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run()
>   at WinCeMessage.Program.Main()

(I believe) The file where these messages are kept is the System.SR.dll, which gets deployed to the device when I run it in Visual Studio.  I docked the emulator, and verified that file is present.

This is the code from System.SR.dll throwing the exception:

```
internal Assembly InternalGetSatelliteAssembly(CultureInfo culture, Version version, bool throwOnFileNotFound)
{
    if (culture != null)
    {
        Assembly assembly = null;
        AssemblyName name = this.GetName();
        if (name != null)
        {
            name.Version = version;
            name.CultureInfo = culture;
            if (name.Name != null)
            {
                name.Name = string.Concat(name.Name, ".resources");
                name.CodeBase = null;
            }
            try
            {
                StackCrawlMark stackCrawlMark = StackCrawlMark.LookForMyCaller;
                assembly = Assembly.BCL_System_Reflection_Assembly_LoadFromName(name, false, null, ref stackCrawlMark);
            }
            catch (IOException oException)
            {
                assembly = null;
            }
            if (assembly != null)
            {
                if (assembly == this)
                {
                    if (!throwOnFileNotFound)
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new FileNotFoundException();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (!throwOnFileNotFound)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new FileNotFoundException();
                }
            }
        }
        return assembly;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up making a new solution, that one seemed broken for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying the `TcpClient()` method is throwing an exception and you are not able to catch it?

VS2008's IntelliSense shows only 3 exceptions that are thrown when creating a new `TcpClient()` instance:

```
try {
  TcpClient client = new TcpClient("abcd", 1234);
} catch (ArgumentNullException) {
  Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException");
} catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException) {
  Console.WriteLine("ArgumentOutOfRangeException");
} catch (SocketException) {
  Console.WriteLine("SocketException");
}
```

Place a break point on your exception.

My guess is, though, that your port number is out of range.

Comment: Yeah.  Check out my stacktrace, the SocketException constructor actually throws a file not found exception:  System.Net.Sockets.SocketException..ctor().  Also, this is specific ton the compact framework.  The full framework doesn't have to look up it's exception message like this

Comment: I know this overload for `TcpClient` allows you to specify the Host and Port, but there is also a version that accepts no arguments. I guess so one can add them later. Does that version bomb on you, too? Sometimes one version will not work, but another version will.

Comment: If no exception was thrown, then my test would be useless.  I'm trying to have an exception thrown so that I can ensure the correct exception message gets loaded.  Currently that's not happening